# Переворот экрана в Cubian Desktop (cubieboard A10)

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

У меня есть [cubieboard a10](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubieboard), на котором стоит  и монитор [подключенный через vga](https://github.com/cubieplayer/Cubian/wiki/VGA-output), но появилась проблема, перевернуть экран. Читал много тем по этому поводу, но ничего не получается.
При вводе команды:

```
xrandr -o inverted
```

Пишет:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  149 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  2 (RRSetScreenConfig)
Serial number of failed request:  14
Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

Пробовал добавлять настройки в `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-sunxifb.conf`
Как написано тут:
http://lauri.xn--vsandi-pxa.com/2014/04/debian-jessie-sunxi-packages.html
Но ничего не поменялось.

При попытки создать файл настроек командой `Xorg :1 -configure`
Пишет вот это:

```
root@Cubian:~# Xorg :1 -configure
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-armmp-lpae armv7l Debian
Current Operating System: Linux Cubian 3.4.79-sun4i #28 PREEMPT Fri Oct 10 03:17:31 CST 2014 armv7l
Kernel command line: console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait loglevel=8 panic=10 console=tty2 hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=EDID:0 consoleblank=0 loglevel=0
Build Date: 09 February 2015 10:20:48AM
xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u6 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>)
Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Feb 10 18:21:42 2016
List of video drivers:
nouveau
r128
mach64
fbturbo
radeon
ati
fbdev
vesa
No devices to configure. Configuration failed.
Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

Вот лог Xorg:
https://yadi.sk/i/_TxJDfCvocnZN
https://yadi.sk/i/tFPNzYssocnaT

Возможно я чего-то не до понимаю.
Подскажите пожалуйста что делать и как повернуть всё таки этот монитор.
Все обновлял и cubian и все пакеты.

Comment: Файл /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-device.conf посмотреть можно?

Comment: Я на своей Raspberry Pi в Raspbian (по сути, тот же Debian для ARM, что и Cubian) решал такой вопрос путем добавления параметра ядру `lcd_rotate=2` для поворота на 180°. Возможно, что-то похожее присутствует в Cubian.

Comment: В Cubian такое не прокатит: нет у него таких параметров, инициализация идет через script.bin, со своими параметрами.

Comment: @AndrewHobbit 50-device - нету такого файла, только 20-sunxifb, который я скопировал из статьи, которая указана выше, но это не чего не поменяло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить (или исправить если секция уже есть) в xorg.conf или, если используется автоматическая генерация конфига, в /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-sunxifb.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Allwinner A10/A13 FBDEV"
    Driver          "fbturbo"
    Option          "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
    Option          "SwapbuffersWait" "true"
    Option          "AccelMethod" "G2D"
    Option          "Rotate" "UD"
    Option         "SWCursor" "On"
EndSection
```

Перезапустить "иксы". Для поворота на 90 и 270 градусов, указать вместо "UD", "CW" и "CCW" соответсвенно. Выдержка из man:
Option "Rotate" "string" Enable rotation of the display. The supported values are "CW" (clockwise, 90 degrees), "UD" (upside down, 180 degrees) and "CCW" (counter clockwise, 270 degrees). Implies use of the shadow framebuffer layer. Default: off.

Comment: А в какую секцию нужно это вставлять или это сама идёт в место Section и EndSection ?

Comment: В секцию "Device", поправил код в ответе. После изменения конфига надо иксы перезапустить, изменения на лету не подхватываются.

Comment: Ничего не поменялось, вот лог: https://yadi.sk/d/bwtEU6yapHmQD

Comment: Может можно как то посмотреть устройства которые он определяет, а которые нет? У вас тоже cubieboard?

Comment: Был "кубик", но стояла на нем Lubuntu. Тоже вопрос был с поворотом, прописывал параметры в xorg.conf, так привычнее, хоть и неправильно. Xorg.conf можно создать так: Xorg :0 -configure. Какие файлы есть в /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ ?

Comment: 10-evdev.conf    50-synaptics.conf  99-sunxifb.conf
10-monitor.conf  50-wacom.conf
Вот они все: https://yadi.sk/d/ZsYyjcIVpKZ6A   При вводе `Xorg :0 -configure` ,пишет вот это: http://joxi.ru/el2ZyEVhL8DMmJ.jpg

Comment: Попробовал скопировать их в `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`, добавив `Option          "Rotate" "inverted"`, не помогло, всё точно так же

Comment: Перед тем как X конфигурировать надо их остановить, об этом Вам система говорит когда Xorg :0 -configure запускаете. Удалите все из /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d, замените содержимое /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-sunxifb.conf на https://yadi.sk/i/Uo3iVd5HpKmiX перезапустите иксы (или перезагрузитесь).

Comment: Попробовал конфигурировать, но не чего не вышло, вот что пишет: http://joxi.ru/752aMEQueGeP20.jpg Вот логи: https://yadi.sk/i/ziRyqNIhpLpSf Удалил и заменил файл, как вы сказали, всё получилось! Но только на бок, как перевернуть его не на 90 градусов ,а на 180? У меня что-то не получается, если писать inverted, как я нашёл, то не он не переворачивается вообще.

Comment: При вводе `xrandr -o inverted` пишет: `extension missing` и не чего не происходит, ему чего-то не хватает?

Comment: xrandr не сработает, пока драйвера еще на запилили для mali400 нормальные. Вместо "CCW" укажите "UD". Выдержка из man `Option "Rotate" "string"
        Enable rotation of the display. The supported  values  are  "CW" (clockwise,  90  degrees),  "UD"  (upside down, 180 degrees) and 
        "CCW" (counter clockwise,  270  degrees).  Implies  use  of  the shadow framebuffer layer.   Default: off.`

Comment: Всё работает с `UD`, спасибо огромное за помощь! Подправьте ответ и отвечу как правильный.

Comment: Поправил. Рад что помог.